# SQL Trigger firing for column update when not updated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I think my problem is around the following lines...

```
IF NOT UPDATE(DateCompleted) or NOT EXISTS(SELECT DateCompleted FROM DELETED where DateCompleted is null)
RETURN
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that the trigger only fires if the `DateCompleted` has been updated with a date where previously there was none.

I just ran a test where the Job was updated and `DateCompleted` has not been set (still NULL) but the trigger fired

Steve

```
        CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgJobCompletion] 
       ON  [dbo].[Job] 
       AFTER UPDATE
    AS 

    -- Make sure DateCompleted was changed and was previously NULL
    IF NOT UPDATE(DateCompleted) or NOT EXISTS(SELECT DateCompleted FROM DELETED where DateCompleted is null)
        RETURN

    -- Only interested in Maintenance, Contract Repair or Repair Jobs
    DECLARE @JobTypeID as int;
    select @JobTypeID = inserted.LookUpJobTypeID from inserted;
    IF NOT @JobTypeID = 9 AND NOT @JobTypeID = 2  AND NOT @JobTypeID = 1
        RETURN 

    DECLARE @JobID as int;
    DECLARE @ContractNumber as int;
    DECLARE @SiteID as int;
    select @JobID = inserted.ID from inserted;
    select @ContractNumber = Contract.ContractNumber from inserted left join Site on Site.ID = inserted.SiteID left join Contract on Contract.ID = Site.ContractID;
    select @SiteID = inserted.SiteID from inserted;

    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        -- Insert statements for trigger here

        insert into JobCompletedLog(JobID,LookUpJobTypeID,ContractNumber,SiteID,LogCreated) 
        values(@JobID,@JobTypeID,@ContractNumber,@SiteID,getdate());


    END
```

Comment: The trigger will fire each time an `UPDATE` happens on the table `[Job]`, so if I understood your requirement. You want to insert the data into `JobCompletedLog` only when the `DateCompleted` column  was `NULL` prior to the update

Comment: I think DateCompleted column is nullable and you want to fire trigger when DateCompleted column changed or when a row has DateCompleted deleted. If so you should change your not exists sub query. Try below lines instaead of yours.

    IF NOT UPDATE(DateCompleted) or NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED where DateCompleted is null)

Comment: Joby: the requirement is that when DateCompleted is populated with a date (and it was previously NULL) then I want to insert into the JobCompletedLog

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger has a fundamental flaw, which is that is works on the premise that the memory-resident table `inserted` only contains one row, e.g.

```
select @JobID = inserted.ID from inserted;
```

`inserted` can contain multiple rows, and you are essentially assigning one value at random from this table to the scalar variable `@JobID`.

Similarly `UPDATE(DateCompleted)` will return true if *any* row has been updated, so you can still inserted records for jobs that have not completed.

Even if you think that only one row will be updated at a time because of other processes, you should **always** write your trigger to work for multiple rows. No exceptions.

Your trigger should be something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgJobCompletion] 
ON  [dbo].[Job] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT JobCompletedLog(JobID,LookUpJobTypeID,ContractNumber,SiteID,LogCreated) 
    SELECT  i.ID, i.LookUpJobTypeID, c.ContractNumber, i.siteID, GETDATE()
    FROM    inserted AS i
            INNER JOIN deleted AS d
                ON d.ID = i.ID
            LEFT JOIN Site AS s
                ON s.ID = i.SiteID
            LEFT JOIN Contract AS c
                ON c.ID = s.ContractID
    WHERE   i.LookUpJobTypeID IN (9, 2, 1)  -- Only interested in Maintenance, Contract Repair or Repair Jobs
    AND     i.DateCompleted IS NOT NULL     -- Date Completed has been set
    AND     d.DateCompleted IS NULL         -- Date Completed was previously null

END
```

Comment: Jeez, so much more elegant than what I produced ! And that makes it much easier to see what you mean about multiple entries in Inserted and how I link to Deleted but I don't get the...  Similarly UPDATE(DateCompleted) will return true if any row has been updated...I thought that would only return rows where DateCompleted had been updated ??

Answer (score 0):

I think DateCompleted column is nullable and you want to fire trigger when DateCompleted column changed or when a row has DateCompleted deleted. If so you should change your not exists sub query. Try below lines instaead of yours.

IF NOT UPDATE(DateCompleted) or NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED where DateCompleted is null)